# What is the proper way to block visitors from one specific folder, but allow my IP to see it (PHP)?

Tags: php, .htaccess, robots.txt

Let's say I have a site at www.example.com and I decide I want to have a French version of the same site at the URL www.example.com/fr

But at first, I only want myself to be able to see www.example.com/fr and anything within it (i'd like to block both "regular" visitors and any bots.

Can I block everyone except my IP from just that folder/section?  If so is it done via htaccess, robots.txt, a combo of both, some other way?

I know for visitors, I can add this to my htaccess:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from (my ip address)
```

But can I tweak that to say everyone can go to everything EXCEPT the "fr" folder?

And I know for bots (i.e. google) this robots.txt file would be used at the root of my main site, if I wanted to keep bots from visiting:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

So do I create another robots.txt in the "fr" folder with that in it?  Or would it have to be done via the original robots.txt file in the main site root?

Comment: Just put a .htaccess file with your "order deny,allow" section in the folder you want to protect. You can have different htaccess files with different rules in each folder.

Comment: use your Ip adress and user agent

Comment: You can only have one `robots.txt` file and it needs to be in the top folder. However, all you need to do there is to add an extra row with `Disallow: /fr`. However, that's not needed if you have a htaccess in the /fr folder, since no one except your IP would be able to read that file anyway.

Comment: Makes total sense, and I didn't realize you could have multiple htaccess, so thank you!  Add an answer with this info and I'll mark as best if you'd like.

Comment: Added an answer.

Comment: The robots.txt file is a polite notice which is only respected by well behaved bots. mod_authz_host (the component in Apache addressed by your example htaccess file) policy is **enforced** by your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have different `.htaccess` files in each folder, so just put a `.htaccess` in the `/fr` folder with the content:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from (your ip address)
```

Regarding `robots.txt`, you can only have one which needs to be in the web root `/`. However, if you want to ask robots not to read a specific folder, all you need to do is to add a new row:

```
Disallow: /fr
```

`robots.txt` can contain many `Disallow`-rows to different files/folders.
Just remember, robots doesn't *have* to respect your robots.txt-file. It's not a safe way to hide folders.

***Note:*** If you have the above `.htaccess` in the `/fr` folder, you don't need to add it to `robots.txt` as well, since robots won't be able to read that folder anyway.

- [You can read more about .htaccess here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) *(including why you should avoid using .htaccess if you have access to the main server config).*
- [You can read more about robots.txt here](http://www.robotstxt.org/)